# Spelling mistake regex

Tags: regular-expression, spelling

I have a large text file of an OCR'd book where many words have been broken and hyphenated at the end of a line. Eg.

```
In his newest book of language ex- 
ploration, Professor Asimov ranges over
```

I can see many ways I might go about cleaning up the file of *these* particular errors but believe the process would go much faster if I were able to compose a **regex** that can find a misspelled word.

Is it possible to specify a regex for a misspelled word. I suspect not, but thought I'd ask anyway.

[Edit]

And by cleaning up the file I mean correcting spelling, formatting etc.

Since posting I've tried out **aspell** but couldn't get it to give me line-numbers (in non-interactive mode); and vim plugin [SpellCheck](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SpellCheck).

The latter works as described and is actually pretty good (despite requiring a 1MB [library](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library).

It would still be cool if I could write a regex for misspelled words though.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Could you clarify what you mean by "cleaning the file"? What are you exactly trying to achieve? Do you need to undo the break for these words?

Comment: There cannot exist a *regex* to find all misspelled words.

Comment: OK, but my question was a regex for *a* misspelled word. :smile:

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean?  I'm not sure how what you are looking for differs from the functionality found in the builtin `:h spell`.  Also, if you show us what you are trying to match and not match we may be able to help with the regular expression.

Comment: If there were regex atoms (like `$` for end-of-line) for misspelled words I could compose a macro to deal rapidly with spelling mistakes.

At the moment with vanilla (g)vim, I have no choice but to mash the keys to move from one spelling mistake to another. In a text with possibly hundreds of spelling mistakes, it's not feasible. 

As for help with regex generally, thanks but I'm ok with composing regex.

Comment: If I’ve understood you correctly, you’re after a regex which will match any word which vim has marked as incorrectly spelt. That’s not possible as the regular expression engine doesn’t have an atom for accessing that kind of information; of course you could always write a function on-the-fly to query all misspelt words in a document and compile them into one long regex but that might be a case of XY problem.

Comment: Also, apologies if you already know this but when you say you have to mash the keys to move from one spelling error to another, you are aware that you can use `]s`?